# Which program is used to create these effects? (see example within)

Tags: animation, 3d

http://www.mynuvia3.com

There's an animation on the front page and eventually I'd like to make something like that. I don't know where to start though.

Which program(s) could be used to make such animations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After Effects. I'm guessing that the primitives were created in either Illustrator or Photoshop and the flares, drops, etc. were accomplished using various plug-ins that manipulated particles and lighting.

**You can find tutorials for this :**

1. [Excellent Adobe After Effects Tutorials](http://www.noupe.com/tutorial/50-excellent-adobe-after-effects-tutorials.html)
2. [Adobe After Effects Tutorials](http://www.videocopilot.net/tutorials/)

Comment: Wow. There's definitely a lot of particle-system action going on there! Sure looks like it came out of AE.

Comment: Very nice edit. I'd doubly +1 you if I could.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to know. It could be any combination of Photoshop, Flash, Illustrator, any number of 3D software, any number of video editing tools, any number of video effects tools, etc